# html code to install an google chrome extension (.crx)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been doing some googling but I can't seem to find the code to install a custom extension just like it would on the Chrome store. I have my own link that links to a .crx file on my Dropbox. How would I be able to install that .crx file through html or JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upload your extension to the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps). This step is *not* optional; [since January 2014, Google Chrome has not supported installs of extensions from any other location](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html). (This means that you cannot use Dropbox to host your extension. No, there is no way around this. Malware authors have abused every other installation method that was made available.)

Once you have done so, you can direct users to your extension's download page on the Chrome Web Store to install your extension, or use [inline installation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation) to prompt them to install it directly from your web site.